# sign() much slower in python than matlab?

Tags: python, sign, benchmarking

I have a function in python that basically takes the sign of an array (75,150), for example.
I'm coming from Matlab and the time execution looks more or less the same less this function.
I'm wondering if sign() works very slowly and you know an alternative to do the same.

Thx,

Comment: Joseph Dunn you are right, I forgot a lot of important things: the data is complex array but then I use sign(real(x)) and sign(imag(y))

Comment: A factor of 10 in speed execution is normal between MATLAB and python, since MATLAB has a JIT(Just-In-Time compiler). Using pypy instead of CPython *could* improve python's performances near to MATLAB's ones.

Comment: Adding to what Bakuriu said: Python code using numpy tends to be around the same speed as MATLAB as long as you can write things in terms of builtin vectorized functions, but an order of magnitude slower whenever you have to write an explicit loop. Unfortunately, some things are hard to express in terms of vector functions… but some things are actually simpler that way, as Joseph Dunn's answer shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you if this is faster or slower than Matlab, since I have no idea what numbers you're seeing there (you provided no quantitative data at all). However, as far as alternatives go:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randn(75, 150)
aSign = np.sign(a)
```

Testing using `%timeit` in [`IPython`](http://ipython.org/):

```
In [15]: %timeit np.sign(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 180 µs per loop
```

Because the loop over the array (and what happens inside it) is implemented in optimized C code rather than generic Python code, it tends to be about an order of magnitude faster—in the same ballpark as Matlab.

---

Comparing the exact same code as a numpy vectorized operation vs. a Python loop:

```
In [276]: %timeit [np.sign(x) for x in a]
1000 loops, best of 3: 276 us per loop

In [277]: %timeit np.sign(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 63.1 us per loop
```

So, only 4x as fast here. (But then `a` is pretty small here.)

Comment: It might be better if you showed how `np.sign` outperformed a Python loop around a `sign` function, instead of just showing how fast it is in absolute terms on a particular compute. I've added a test from my system, but it would be more useful with yours.

Comment: @abarnert Apologies, I thought that (75,150) was OP's array dimensions, not OP's entire array. What you say makes sense.